# Testing Spring WebFlux with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

I'm trying to test an use case that returns a Flux of an object but it is not working. This is the interface implemented by the use case:

```
public interface Import {
    Flux<ImportedData> execute(List<InputParams> params, int importId);
}
```

If I mock the `params` argument, it always returns a NPE: Mockito says the mapper returned a null Publisher.

But when I use the `params` argument as `Mockito.any()`, it works fine. The `any()` method does not apply to me, since I have to test a specific situation.

This is the test code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ImportTests {
    @Mock
    private Import import;

    private SortData sortData;

    private final int importId = 1;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        //this is not working
        when(this.import.execute(getInputParams(), this.importId)).thenReturn(MockResults.getImportedData()); 

        //this works
        when(this.import.execute(Mockito.any(), eq(this.importId))).thenReturn(MockResults.getImportedData()); 

        this.sortData = new SortData(this.import);
    }

    @Test
    public void sortTest() {

        List<RawData> sortedRawData = new ArrayList();
        //this is where the NPE occurs
        this.sortData.execute().subscribe(sortedRawData::add);

        //Assert.equals()...;
    }

    private List<InputParams> getInputParams() {
        InputParams input1 = new InputParams(1, "someThing", 2);
        InputParams input2 = new InputParams(2, "someThing", 4);
        InputParams input3 = new InputParams(3, "someThing", 5);
        return Array.asList(input1, input2, input3);
    }
}
```

The WebFlux concept is kind of new to me. I thought it could be something related to it, but I'm not sure. 
Does someone have experienced similar issues?

Comment: you are setting up your mock to accept that SPECIFIC list that you created. That list that has that object id. You have not shown your test, but you are probably not passing that specific List, you are probably creating a new list and the new list is not the same list that you setup in the mock.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf it seems something like you said. But I'm a little confused. I have edited with the unit test and added the NPE message. Trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Post your sortData class

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I figured out what happened, thanks to your comment: the number of objects in the `params` list was different of what it was expected when processed by the `sortData` use case! Thanks!